# How to save bootstrap carousel current slide index when changing page

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using a cycled Bootstrap Carousel as header of a website in PHP, is there any way to keep the memory of the LAST slide reached when I change the page of my website?

The carousel code is saved at the top of each page (included in one PHP file) and I'm using PHP session to save variables.

I don't know how the carousel works, the idea would be to update the index in the variable SESSION['slideNumber'] each time the carousel change slide. Feel free to ask me more details.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you can use this event to set index of current slide into the session or cookie. This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.

```
  $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
    // do something…
  })
```

additional options in bootstrap:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-events